# PySpark: modify 2 column values when these 2 columns simultaneously satisfy a condition

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a PySpark Dataframe where I want to change the values of 2 column simultaneously based on the filter condition involving those 2 columns. I'll give an hypothetical example as I cannot share the data.

+---+----+
| Id |Rank|
+--+---+
|  a |   5 |
|  b |   7 |
|  c |   8 |
|  d |   1 |
|    |   9  |
+--+---+

Condition: when Id == "  " and Rank == 9 then Id = "A1" and Rank = 0, Otherwise no change. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to judge the two columns separately.

```
data = [
    ('a', 5),
    ('b', 7),
    ('c', 8),
    ('d', 1),
    (' ', 8),
    (' ', 9),
    ('e', 9)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'rank'])
df = df.selectExpr(
    'if((id = " " and rank = 9), "A3", id) as id',
    'if((id = " " and rank = 9), 0, rank) as rank'
)
df.show(truncate=False)

# +---+----+
# |id |rank|
# +---+----+
# |a  |5   |
# |b  |7   |
# |c  |8   |
# |d  |1   |
# |   |8   |
# |A3 |0   |
# |e  |9   |
# +---+----+
```

Comment: Hey your solution works for the above case. However, can you guide me if I have a case where I have 60 more columns which are to be kept the same, how can I keep them in the dataframe? Many thanks!

Comment: 1 Use the `withColumn()` method to retain the original column and generate a new column.
2 If there are too many columns, use `list comprehensions` to generate the final SQL expression.